# How to console log a click event in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Here is the code I was trying. I don't where I am doing wrong can anyone please point out it. It is not printing the message into the console.

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  methods:{
    nextPage: function(){
      console.log('you have clicked me');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<html>
  <body id='app'>
  <button v-on:click = "nextPage">Click ME</button>
  <div class='key'> c </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  methods: {
    nextPage: function() {
      console.log('you have clicked me')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <button v-on:click="nextPage">Click ME</button>
      <div class='key'> c </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Never mount `Vue` to the `html` or `body` tags as you can see in my example I created a new `div` and gave it the `app` id then wrapped it around all the page contents.